# Azure Table "DELETE" returning "inputs is not valid"

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-entity1) my `DELETE` request should be working ?

A `GET` request works perfectly, i.e. :

```
curl -X GET "https://foo.table.core.windows.net/bar(PartitionKey='alice',RowKey='bob')?sv=2017-04-17&ss=qt&srt=o&sp=rwdlacup&se=2021-08-22T23:33:21Z&st=2017-08-01T15:33:21Z&sip=10.10.10.0-10.10.10.255&spr=https&sig=SECRET_SQUIRREL"
```

Returns the data. No problem.  All the content is shown correctly.

If I then change `-X GET` to `-X DELETE` and leave everything else identical, i.e. :

```
curl -X DELETE "https://foo.table.core.windows.net/bar(PartitionKey='alice',RowKey='bob')?sv=2017-04-17&ss=qt&srt=o&sp=rwdlacup&se=2021-08-22T23:33:21Z&st=2017-08-01T15:33:21Z&sip=10.10.10.0-10.10.10.255&spr=https&sig=SECRET_SQUIRREL"
```

The service returns :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>InvalidInput</code><message xml:lang="en-US">One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId:5d3bce31-0002-0054-4b18-1cba44000000
Time:2017-08-23T14:02:00.3177321Z</message></error>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation for [`Delete Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-entity1), you are missing `If-Match` request header. From the documentation link:

[image]

Please include `If-Match` header in your request with value as `*` and the request should work.